# Approximating $\frac{(n+1)H_n -n}{n^2}$

Tags: approximation, harmonic-numbers

I have the following value

$$\frac{(n+1)H_n -n}{n^2}$$

But it is complicated to write, so I want to write a simple approximation to use it. I guess I can just write

$$\frac{(n+1)H_n -n}{n^2}\approx \frac{H_n-1}{n} \approx \frac{H_n}{n} \approx \frac{\ln n}{n}$$

Is this a good approximation, or is there a clearly better one? Thanks.

Comment: "better" depends on intended use.  What do you want your approximation to be good at/good for?

Comment: For a paper. Is there a clearly better approximation that has also a short expression? I do not intend to have any specific results on the quality of the approximation, but I'd like to be within, say +-1 range (which may not be possible since the Euler-Mascheroni constant is approx 0.577)

Comment: You want it to be within $\pm 1$ range of the actual value? That sounds hard..

Comment: @GarethMa : Actually, very easy.  For positive integer $n$ (which is suggested by the form and since OP has given no domain for his function), $0$ is within $\pm 1$ of the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $\gamma > 0.5$, the approximation $$\frac{\log n}{n}$$ is superior to $$\frac{\gamma + \log n}{n}$$ despite $$\gamma = \lim_{n \to \infty} H_n - \log n.$$  This is because you write $$\frac{H_n - 1}{n} \approx \frac{H_n}{n},$$ which means you are introducing an error on the order of $O(1/n)$ with that step.  If you write instead $$\frac{-1 + \gamma + \log n}{n},$$ you get an approximation that is asymptotically better than $\log n/n$ for large $n$.  This in turn is due to the fact that in your first step, you introduce an error of order $O(n^{-2})$ by changing $(n+1)/n^2$ into $1/n$.

If you perform a series expansion about infinity for $$f(n) = \frac{(n+1)H_n - n}{n^2},$$ you get $$\frac{-1 + \gamma + \log n}{n} + \frac{1 + 2\gamma + 2 \log n}{2n^2} + \frac{5}{12n^3} - \frac{1}{12n^4} + \frac{1}{120n^5} + \frac{1}{120n^6} + O(n^{-7}).$$  The first term of the expansion is the approximation we described above that outperforms yours.  Adding the second term in increases the complexity of the expression substantially but improves the approximation to within $O(n^{-3})$.  We can try the order $(1,1)$ Padé approximant $$\frac{2 (\gamma -1)^2}{2 \gamma  (n-1)-2 n-1}+\frac{\log n}{n-1}$$ which does even better than the second order series expansion.

Comment: Note: The first approximation $\frac{-1+\gamma+\log n}{n}$ is a lower bound (under-estimation), and the second approximation $\frac{2(\gamma - 1)^2}{2\gamma(n-1)-2n-1}+\frac{\log(n)}{n-1}$ is an upper bound (over-estimation). I do not know how to prove it, just used a python script to verify

Comment: Interesting is the $[2,2]$ Padé approximant. For $n=10$ it gives a relative error of  $0.00053$% while the $[1,1]$ gives $0.01680$%

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to @heropup answer and solution, we could use for
$$f(n) = \frac{(n+1)H_n - n}{n^2}$$
$$\frac{-1 + \gamma + \log n}{n} + \frac{1 + 2\gamma + 2 \log n}{2n^2} + \frac{5}{12n^3}\left(1-\frac{2310 n+559 } {50 \left(231 n^2+79 n+31\right) } \right) $$ which is equivalent to an $O\left(\frac{1}{n^8}\right)$ expansion.

For $n=10$, the relative error is $1.71\times 10^{-8}$%.